# How to integrate transactions with DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, signalr

I am creating an app that has multiple clients that can update the same data so I plan to use this method to update fruits save them to the database then use SignalR to update all other clients. I am trying to design the code to avoid concurrency issues So I have copied this code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations) I was wondering how to incorporate transactions with this bit of code(I have attempted but not sure if its correct or necessary)? or because it's designed to handle concurrency do I even need transactions?

To create a concurrency issue I set the breakpoint to `dbContext.SaveChanges();` and update the data in the database.

```
app.MapPut("UpdateFruits", async (string message, IHubContext<ChatHub> context, DatabaseContext dbContext) =>
{
    //message(Param) = { "ID":"2","DisplayName":"Fruit","Leaf":null,"State":"Chopped"}
    using var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        // Fetch a person from database and change phone number
        var fruit = dbContext.Set<Fruit>().Single(p => p.ID == 1);
        fruit.State = State.Chopped;
        fruit.DisplayName = "test";

        var saved = false;
        while (!saved)
        {
            try
            {
                // Attempt to save changes to the database
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            
                saved = true;             
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.Entity is Fruit)
                    {
                        var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                        var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                        foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
                        {
                            var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
                            var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

                            // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
                            // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
                        }

                        // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
                        entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException(
                            "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                            + entry.Metadata.Name);                      
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        transaction.Commit();
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fruit);
        await context.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "FromServer", jsonString);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
    return Results.NoContent();
});
```

Model:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public List<Leaf>? Leaf{ get; set; }
}

public class Leaf
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public List<Vein>? Vein{ get; set; }
}

public class Vein
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

DBContext:

```
using EAS.API.PropertyManagement.Entities;
using GFX.Suite.API.GFX.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections;

namespace EAS.API.PropertyManagement.Core;

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    Random rnd = new Random();
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Fruit>(builder =>
        {

            builder.ToTable("Fruit");

            //builder.HasMany(c => c.Leaf)
            //.WithOne()
            //.HasForeignKey(f => f.LeafID);

            //var rendertypes = Enumerable
            // .Range(1, 5)
            // .Select(x => new Fruit
            // {
            //     ID = x,
            //     DisplayName = $"Fruits {x}",

            // })
            // .ToList();

            //builder.HasData(rendertypes);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Leaf>(builder =>
        {

            builder.ToTable("Leaf");


            //var properties = Enumerable
            // .Range(1, 5)
            // .Select(x => new Leaf
            // {
            //     ID = x,
            //     DisplayName = $"Leaf {x}",
            // })
            // .ToList();

            //builder.HasData(properties);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Vein>(builder =>
        {

            builder.ToTable("Vein");


            //var properties = Enumerable
            // .Range(1, 5)
            // .Select(x => new Vein
            // {
            //     ID = x,
            //     DisplayName = $"Vein {x}",
            // })
            // .ToList();

            //builder.HasData(properties);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `SaveChanges` already manage a transaction. A explicit transaction is need only when you need to integrate multiple `SaveChanges` in a transaction. In your example, I see one `SaveChange`, then the explicit transaction is unnecessary.  See [EF Core - Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) for more detail.

Comment: @vernou Yes I will use multiple `SaveChanges` I have attached the model I am planning to update

Comment: Can you confirm the `DbContext` lifecycle is scoped?

Comment: In general, you should avoid (if you can) using transactions.  EF already wraps all changes to the DbContext in a single transaction, so if 1 fails, they all fail.  Occasionally you may need to create a wrapper transaction (like you are doing), but it doesn't look like you need to in your case.  Just update all the entities before calling SaveChanges and yuo should be fine.

Comment: @vernou I am not sure what a scoped `DBContext` but I have attached what my DB context looks like and I am relying on the instance from the `app.MapPut` parameter in my API. Intentions in next comment...

Comment: I will have multiple WPF clients calling this method. e.g if I have 5 Wpf clients making a call to the one API endpoint. So I have created this small `Fruit` example to try and accomplish solutions for two scenarios 1. let's say I have 5 apples Client A cuts an apple with ID = 2 the state of apple with ID =2 should be in a state where it cut and no other client should be able to cut apple with ID = 2 even if they click the buttons at the same time assuming client A won the race to the click.

Comment: 2.  Another solution to handle instances where the last request should always be the latest data and use SignalR to update all the other clients

Comment: `DbContext` lifecycle is defined when `DbContext` is registered to DI container. The method `AddDbContext` has a override to define the lifecycle. By default, it's scoped.

Comment: Maybe [Tutorial: Handle concurrency with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency) can help.